# Is there ArcGIS (ideally) solution for spill modeling from particular pour point on crude oil pipeline?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelling, oil-gas

wondering if anyone knows of a solution for spill modeling from a particular pour point on a crude oil pipeline? I currently have all my data within ArcGIS (DEM, major/moderate/minor watercourses, drains, embankments) so would ideally be looking for an ESRI solution, but I'm open to other options.

I did look into ArcHydro, but as far a I can tell wont let me input different variables such as spill volume and oil/soil density. I ideally would also need a model that calculates losses from oil adhesion to land over the oiled path, oil pooling in large depressions on the land surface, and oil evaporation to the atmosphere.

Thanks!

Comment: That's quite a lot you're asking for! You're right about ArcHydro, since it's not really about volumes at all (generally speaking). If I were you I'd start by looking into [Modflow](http://water.usgs.gov/ogw/modflow/) and [Feflow](http://www.feflow.info/), but you might need several models to handle all cases you mention.

Comment: Interesting question! I have not personally worked with [Leapfrog Hydro](http://www.leapfrog3d.com/products/leapfrog-hydro) but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but it looks like Modflow, Feflow, and Leapfrog all have the same limitations as ArcHydro. Perhaps I am asking for too much...

Comment: Maybe [Hec-ras](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/) can help you?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a product called **[OILMAPLAND from RPS APASA](http://www.asascience.com/software/oilmap/oilmapland.shtml)** that may be worth you reviewing because:

> OILMAPLAND is a land and surface water spill model system for
>   simulating oil and chemical releases from pipelines and storage
>   facilities.

and one of its listed features is that:

> The model runs within a stand-alone GIS or as an extension to ArcGIS®
>   for complete integration with existing facility data, High Consequence
>   Area data, terrain models and surface water networks.

Comment: Perfect! Its almost like someone read this post and created a software package based on it...!

Comment: Have just been in contact with RPS APASA who tell me - "we can provide services using OILMAP-Land but we do not sell the software. If you are interested in services, we can quote based on the project requirements". They don't actually point this out on their website...

Comment: @Brian I thought it read like a COTS product too

Answer (score 0):

Look at this web page and other pages of this site too: https://response.restoration.noaa.gov/oil-and-chemical-spills/oil-spills/response-tools/gnome-suite-oil-spill-modeling.html

Comment: Hi Vulgar and welcome on the GIS community. When answering post, you should explain and describe what's in your link. You can follow the [SO guideline for help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)